# How can I get the Region Format in Android?

Tags: android

I need to access the Region Format in my application and display the dates according to that.

In iPhone, we can get the Region Format in

Settings -> General -> International -> Region Format.

Is there any options to get the same, in Android?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
GregorianCalendar gc= new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy-MM-dd");

String formatted = sdf.parse(gc.getTime());
```

when inizializing SimpleDateFormat you can add a custom Locale format otherwise it will pick default os, eg

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ITALY);
```